# I can use existing plumbing lines to make a bathroom and why the black pipes are inside the white pipes

Tags: plumbing

[image]

I can use existing plumbing lines to make a bathroom and why black pipes are inside white pipes

Comment: Welcome Richard.  You need to add much more detail for "i can use existing plumbing lines to make a bathroom" **In order to get an informed answer it is best to provide as much info as you can and have specific questions**.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Ed's answer. When drainlines are encased in concrete the sleeve protects them from damage during construction. There's usually a lot of equipment or heavy material being moved around and you don't want them damaged. They're tough to repair if broken at the floorline.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bathroom rough in. I also sleeve drain lines many times if just roughed in, the 3 inch is for the toilet and the 1-1/2 for a sink, if there is a 2” it is normally for a shower or this is how I plumb them.